# JSON response being output to browser

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'm using a Symfony2 Controller to return a JSON string:

```
return new Response(json_encode(array('errors' => $errors)));
```

Basically, I want to return errors to the form. But when I call the action, the JSON output is displayed in my browser. But I want to call the JSON in a callback function in JavaScript (jQuery).

I tried to set the Content-Type to `application/json`, but it doesn't work in IE because IE wants to save the file.

My JavaScript:

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("action");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Ouptut errors
        }
    });
});
```

What can I do?

Comment: I guess you are using your javascript wrong. Show us your javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the form submission on click so that it is only submit via `$.ajax()`:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form being submit on click

    var url = $(this).attr("action");    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Ouptut errors
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you (; That does work for Firefox, but not for IE. So I added a `return false` statement at the end of the function.